# How to take a tuple of two lists from user input?

Tags: python-3.x, list, input, tuples, user-input

How to take a tuple of two equal-size lists from **user input** at a bash terminal from within a python script?
Let's assume we want the program to register the following tuple

```
([0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1], [1000, 100, 10, 1])
```

The only condition to grab them is to do that in pairs of two: 0.001, 1000 and then 0.01, 100 and etc.

---

**Explanation**

the code takes 0.001 and 1000 first

it then takes 0.01 and 100 second

it then takes 0.1 and 10 third

and finally it takes 1 and 1.

Once it has taken all of them, it will arrange them in the said tuple.

Comment: could you explain better? what do you mean by _pairs of two_? i.e 0.1, 10 are a pair but 0.1 and 1 not?! what is the exat user input and what would be the desire output? also a wrong output (based on an input) can help

Comment: Just added the explanation

Comment: Okay, so where are you stuck? What do you imagine are the logical steps to solving the problem, and what can't you do yourself? As a reminder, this is not a code-writing service; you should have a *specific* question in mind about the *problem you are encountering when trying to solve the problem yourself* - not just a specification for the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loop to take inputs.

```
lst1 = list()
lst2 = list()
for i in range(4):
    lst1.append(input("input 1 :"))
    lst2.append(input("input 2 :"))

tup = (lst1, lst2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
N = 4
# user input in this way:
# 1 2
x =  [tuple(map(lambda x: int(x), input().split())) for _ in range(N)]

# user input in this way:
# 1 
# 2
# x = [(int(input()), int(input())) for _ in range(N)]
```

if you just want to extract the input:

```py
x, y = ([0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1], [1000, 100, 10, 1])
print(tuple(zip(x,y)))
# ((0.001, 1000), (0.01, 100), (0.1, 10), (1, 1))
```

Comment: Thank you A D, but I want the user-input in the bash terminal to be registered.

Comment: The output is a list of tuples instead of a tuple of two lists.